# Сравнение выборки SQL И Variant в Delphi

Tags: delphi, массивы

Добрый день. Есть результат запроса SQLquery в Delphi, А также массив variant.
Количество полученных строк у SQLQuery и у variant может быть неодинаковым.
Как сравнить значения у результата SQLQuery и у Variant и в случае отсутствия какого-то элемента в выборке SQL вывести в Memo данные из Variant которых нет  в SqlQuery?

Comment: Что вы пробовали? Что получилось? Какие возникли проблемы?

Comment: Закинул результат запроса в stringlist MyList.IndexoF(). Если нет индекса то значит в запросе нет того что есть в варианте

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, если мы знаем, что в массиве типа Variant у нас строки, тогда следует привести тип Variant к строковому (и в дальнейшем все-таки стараться работать с defined-типами). Положим, что массив Variant - это `var V: array of Variant`, тогда объявляем новый строковый массив `var A: array of string;` и начинаем преобразование:

```
SetLength(A, Length(V));
for i := 0 to High(A) do A[i] := VarToStr(V[i]);
```

Во-вторых, следует создать второй, строковый динамический массив и *выгрузить* туда данные из SQL-запроса. Пусть он называется `var B: array of string;`

```
SetLength(B, TADODataSet1.RecordCount-1); 
for i := 0 to TADODataSet1.RecordCount-1 do
begin
  B[i] := TADODataSet1.FieldByName("Fieldname").AsString;
  TADODataSet1.Next;
end;
```

С этого момента начинаем работать только с двумя строковыми массивами. Алгоритм сравнения элементов в строковых массивах довольно прост, но я предложу более изящное решение. Подключаем модуль `StrUtils` в котором есть приятная функция `MatchStr`.

Так как по условию задачи нам нужно сравнить значения SQL query со значениями массива Variant, то *главным* в цикле у нас становится именно массив с SQL query (то есть массив `B[]`):

```
for i := 0 to High(B) do
  if not MatchStr(B[i], A) then Memo1.Lines.Add('Отсутствует значение: ' + B[i]);
```

Следует заметить, что функция `MatchStr` производит сравнение строк с учетом регистра. Если регистр не важен, то можно использовать функцию `MatchText` из того же модуля.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться SQLQuery.Locate() для всех значений которые есть в Variant массиве. Правда насколько он эффективен, это уже другой вопрос =)

Документация: [TDataSet.Locate](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet_Locate.html)